# Division in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to take a value that I'm pulling from a database and divide it by 12 and display that number, but I can't seem to get it right.  This is what I have so far to display a value:

```
$<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(//Applications/AveAnnualVolume),'###,###,##0.00')"/>
```

That part works, but I can't figure out how to divide it by 12 and display that instead.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

XPath uses `div` for division since slashes are used as separators.

```
$<xsl:value-of select="format-number(//Applications/AveAnnualVolume div 12,'###,###,##0.00')"/>
```

Comment: Also see https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_formatnumber.asp for format-number syntax