# XML xlst calculate value

Tags: xml, operators, xls, calc

I'm getting a number in xml from a 3rd part provider. I need to display this number divided by 100 and with dicimals. Is this possible in xls?

so

> Number = 40000

```
<xsl:value-of select="number" />
```

> output: 40000

But i need it to be

> output: 400,00

I dont have the option to make the input value different than what Im getting now.

EDIT:

```
<xsl:value-ofselect="Number div 100"> gives 400
```

So im getting close, next is formatting. But with this Im getting an error: "There is an unclosed literal string"

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(Number div 100,'###,###,##0.00')">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447205/division-in-xslt can help a lot

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I was to fast, im getting a "There is an unclosed literal string", with select="format-number(Number div 100,'###,###,##0.00')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(year div 100,'###,###,##0.00')"/>` on http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=tryxsl_if and it worked.

Full XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>40000</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Still got the blues</title>
        <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Virgin records</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Eros</title>
        <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>BMG</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>One night only</title>
        <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1998</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
        <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS</company>
        <price>8.10</price>
        <year>1973</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Maggie May</title>
        <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Pickwick</company>
        <price>8.50</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Romanza</title>
        <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>10.80</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
        <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Black angel</title>
        <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Mega</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
        <artist>Many</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Grammy</company>
        <price>10.20</price>
        <year>1999</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>For the good times</title>
        <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Mucik Master</company>
        <price>8.70</price>
        <year>1995</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Big Willie style</title>
        <artist>Will Smith</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1997</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
        <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Polydor</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1971</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Soulsville</title>
        <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
        <country>Norway</country>
        <company>WEA</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1996</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The very best of</title>
        <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Island</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1990</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Stop</title>
        <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>A and M</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
        <artist>T`Pau</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Siren</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Private Dancer</title>
        <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>Capitol</company>
        <price>8.90</price>
        <year>1983</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Midt om natten</title>
        <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Medley</company>
        <price>7.80</price>
        <year>1983</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
        <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>DECCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1991</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>The dock of the bay</title>
        <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Atlantic</company>
        <price>7.90</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Picture book</title>
        <artist>Simply Red</artist>
        <country>EU</country>
        <company>Elektra</company>
        <price>7.20</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Red</title>
        <artist>The Communards</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>London</company>
        <price>7.80</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Unchain my heart</title>
        <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>EMI</company>
        <price>8.20</price>
        <year>1987</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Full XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
      <th>Number</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:if test="price>10">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(year div 100,'###,###,##0.00')"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, then it must be the software that process the xlst that have a bug.